# Can't deploy React App on heroku, don't understand why?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Here's what Heroku says when I try to deploy:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sweetalert2' in '/tmp/build_477bb6c3/src/components/Funditron'

----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
```

I love you too Heroku but what else do you want from me! :D

Comment: you need to choose your buildpack inside heroku, there is one for react-app, 
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

And read this article can help you set up everything
https://medium.com/make-it-heady/deploying-create-react-app-on-heroku-from-github-49447561f670

Comment: That's just the last part of the error message, and it's not very informative. Please [edit] your question and show us the whole thing.

Comment: exaclty what you give to help you is nothing that's why I suggest you to read and investigate about it, and your package.json is missing { "engines" : { "node" : ">=14.17" } }

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not against heroku, I'd strongly suggest netlify. I mean that what almost all react developers use. It's very simple to use, try it out

Comment: yes but if you need to deploy a React App + a Node server, you can't use Netlify

Comment: In this case, you should deploy your node server to heroku and react to netlify

Comment: That's a common practice

Comment: Meh, I would better use something to do everything than using many different services